# Can you force a browser to always fetch the cached files and not do a round trip for a 304?

Tags: caching, browser, header, http-headers, browser-cache

As I understand, this is how browser caching works. Assuming, a far future header has been set to let's say a year and foo.js is set to be cached. Here are some scenarios:

1. First visit to the page, server returns 200 and foo.js is cached for a year.
2. Next visit, browser checks the cache but has to check the server if foo.js has been modified. If not, server returns a 304 - Not Modified.
3. User is already on the page (and foo.js is in cache) clicks a link to go to another page, browser looks at the cached version of foo.js and serves it without doing a roundtrip to the server and returns a 200 (Cached).
4. User is already on the page (and foo.js is in cache) and for some reason hits F5/Reload, browser checks the cache but has to do a round trip to the server and check if foo.js has been modified. If not, server returns a 304.

As you can see, whenever a page is refreshed, it will always have to do a trip to the server to check if the file has been modified or not. I know this is not a lot and server will only return the header info but a round trip time in some cases are extremely important.

The question is, is there a way I can avoid this since I'm already setting the expiration for the files. I just want it to always fetch it from the cache until the expiration has expired or replace the file with something else (by versioning it).

Comment: 2 doesn't seem right unless the headers say you must always revalidate

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, pressing F5/Ctrl-R is browser specific action, thus leaving the control to browser.

What if the user clears the cache before clicking another action? So, even if there was HTTP specification to forcefully use cache in F5, there's no guarantee that you'll be able to achieve your need.

Simply configure and code to cache wherever maximum possible and leave the rest to user.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, when you navigate to a page (that is entering an address in URL bar or clicking a link), resources are fetched from cache without a HEAD request to server. But when you refresh the page it does the HEAD request ans so the RTT.

This looks more clear in Network tab of IE's Developer Tools. If you see the initator column, it says `navigate` for the first case and `refresh` for `CTRL+R` or `F5`.

You can override the `F5` and `CTRL+R` behavior by adding an event listener on them and doing a `window.location = window.location` and prevent the default behavior by `event.peventDefault` or something similar. This will cause page navigation instead of refresh.

Also, I didn't test the case when the cached resource has actually changed on server. If that turns out to be a problem, you can solve it by version numbering of resources and generation of HTML with URLs pointing to the latest version of the resource (kind of like cache-manifest problem with HTML5 offline applications).

EDIT: This however doesn't solve the problem if user clicks on browser's refresh button; `onbeforeunload` event may help in that case.